# Variations in "Il Gardellino" - Cantabile

Tags: flute, vivaldi

Listening to renditions of Vivaldi's Concerto in D Major, Op 10 No 3, Second Movement - Cantabile, it seems that when it's played as solo piece, the repeats include ornaments that are not in the score. In a recording by Sir James Galway of the entire concerto, there was none of this ornamentation on the repeats.

So, my questions are: Is there a tradition about this? Are the ornaments individual to each player? Is there a written set of standards?

Pahud plays the Cantabile:

Galway plays the Concerto (Cantabilie/Largo) begins at 3:55.

Answer (score 2):

In Baroque music it was traditional to embellish on the repeat.  Many performers these days like to respect these traditions in their modern-day performances.  They are free to do whatever they think appropriate.

Comment: I'm sure there will be other contributors who could answer your last question more accurately than I.

Comment: Thx. I rather suspected that the answer was as you explained. I'm asking because I may play the Cantabile for in church as a prelude, and I'd rather like to have some variation in the repeats. If I tried to create embellishments myself, they'd probably sound rather 20th century.